# Is it safe to modify an argument from in a slot function in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a signal that emits a `std::vector<uint8_t>` which contains a load of data (a buffer).

Then in the receiving objects I have a slot that takes an argument `std::vector<uint8_t> data`

Then I try to decode this data. One of the things I have to do is remove padding, for example:

```
void receive_slot(std::vector<uint8_t> data)
{
    // Remove padding
    if (data.size() > 20)
        data.resize(data.size() - 20);
}
```

Now, I thought that this argument passed in is a copy that I can "do what I want with". However, doing a re-size of larger then ~10 bytes crashes my program. I assume that re-sizing less then ~10 bytes does not crash it only by luck.

I therefore assume that I can't safely do this and should first copy it to a new data buffer.

Can anyone enlighten me regarding this?

Comment: Could you precise a bit more what exactly happen when it crashes? Do you get any message?

Comment: Not much more to go on, but here is the message from windows: `The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\local\projects\Qt\Audio\build-AudioTest-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\debug\AudioTest.exe crashed`

Comment: That's kind of thin, do you perform any other operations than you've shown? Because currently that seems totally fine.

Comment: Couldn't you run the application in the debugger? That should probably tell you where the crash is.

Comment: Try to pass an argument as a reference. You could not modify array in your sample. Because copy is passed to slot. And... don't forget to register metatypes.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov There's no reason to pass the argument into the slot as a reference if your intention is to modify it. It's actually counterproductive to do so. Let the compiler do its thing. That's not the source of the problem anyway, let's not send the asker on a wild goose chase.

Comment: @all, thanks for the information and clarification, problem is now resolved. After "un-focusing" on what I thought was the issue (incorrectly) I found the problem was indeed a few lines later. I was not 100% if I was allowed to modify that argument, but I am now clear on this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide a direct anwser to the question:

Slots in Qt are just normal function calls (when and with which arguments they're called is the difference, managed by Qt), and it's perfectly valid to modify function arguments (when non-const obviously). You're right when you say that you're given a copy and that you can do "do what you want with it".

In this case, the error doesn't purely come from the fact that you're modifying the function argument.

Comment: Thanks for that, this clears the issue up for me :) +1

Answer (score 2):

The code you show is perfectly valid and safe and the problem is elsewhere in your code. Something else is corrupting the memory, and the crash happens in receive_slot by pure chance. It's really easy to verify that: you should have put together the minimal test case below before even asking your question on SO.

Works for me.

```
#include <vector>
#include <QObject>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QAtomicInt>

QAtomicInt n = 0;

class Object : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Q_SIGNAL void source(const std::vector<uint8_t> &);
   Q_SLOT void sink(std::vector<uint8_t> data) {
      // Remove padding
      if (data.size() > 20)
         data.resize(data.size() - 20);
      n.fetchAndAddOrdered(1);
   }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::vector<uint8_t>)

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   qRegisterMetaType<std::vector<uint8_t> >();
   Object src, dstD, dstQ;
   const int N = 1000000;
   // note elision of const & from the parameter types
   dstD.connect(&src, SIGNAL(source(std::vector<uint8_t>)),
               SLOT(sink(std::vector<uint8_t>)));
   dstQ.connect(&src, SIGNAL(source(std::vector<uint8_t>)),
               SLOT(sink(std::vector<uint8_t>)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      std::vector<uint8_t> v;
      v.resize(qrand() % 100);
      emit src.source(v);
   }
   a.processEvents();
   Q_ASSERT(n.loadAcquire() == (2*N));
   return 0;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments, has guided me in the right direction +1